# Using a UTM with a Link Aggregrator

Tags: bonding, intrusion-detection, utm

I consider changing my office's internet access infrastructure to multilpe ADSL lines aggregated with a link aggregator ([Peplink B710](http://www.peplink.com/balance/)).

I plan to place my existing UTM ([FortiGate-100A](http://www.fortinet.com/products/fortigate/100A.html)) after the balancer.

Should I expect any problems with this configuration? I am afraid that the multi link , multi IP network might make the UTM block some traffic with some attack threat false positives.

Does anyone have any experience with this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the network traffic sessions are not stateful end-to-end across the multi-link device, through the UTM, all the way to the end-clients, then some applications may not work. In those cases, the end-point applications may wind up seeing something that looks like a session hijack attack, if multiple IPs (as the result of the multi-link device) are swapped around during any attempted user session.

Comment: So my fears might not be from the UTM but from the sites themselves? The Peplink unit have options to set balancing modes and rules so I will probably set that to keep a client persistent on a single line for HTTP sessions. (Especially important for SSL)

Comment: At least one of the possible problems is that the UTM may NAT its "WAN side" which might then render unforeseen difficulties with the multi-link device, if it is designed for direct client access from its "LAN side" assessment/determination of per user sessions.